# Amazon VPC: ami-vpc-nat: throughput of micro instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am manually setting up an Amazon VPC network, and have a need to create a NAT instance.  Amazon has VPC specialized AMIs that come in various scales. Due to budget considerations, I am ambling towards using a micro instance of ami-vpc-nat.

I am concerned that with only 613mb, a micro instance may struggle when as more instances are put behind the NAT instance.  Please, can anyone who has deployed this microinstance ami-vpc-nat (especially in production) share their thoughts on its performance and throughput.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm responsible for a VPC estate, with long experience of using various instance types and a good understanding of their characteristics. These characteristics can easily be tested and profiled by anyone and relied-upon as (generally) constant *with the exception of* the `t1.micro` type.

The `t1.micro` instance-type is highly variable in both CPU and network performance, since it is essentially using aggregate 'spare' capacity on the host on which it is running (which of course will be running a variety of other instances and instance-types also). It is also subject to aggressive demand throttling on CPU and network usage - 
there is a distinctive profile in force which limits extended high-load usage, and which then adaptively returns capacity to the instance after such a high-load threshold has been reached and capped.

When configuring my VPC estate, I initially downgraded the NAT instance from `m1.small` to `t1.micro`, reasoning that a simple network gateway appliance was unlikely to demand the capacity of the `m1.small` type, and since it was always-on then I should pay the lowest price possible. However, observation (and later confirmation by an Amazon engineer) showed that as the estate grew and NAT load went up, the `t1.micro` throttle profile presented a definite and measurable bottleneck. Switching back to `m1.small`, with its' pre-allocated and constant network bandwidth, eliminated that bottleneck.

In short, your NAT instance will choke your VPC estate internet access if it is a `t1.micro` - traffic into and out of the VPC (other than over a VPN) will quickly trigger the bandwidth throttle as soon as throughput rises for longer than the duration limit, and will stay throttled until demand drops (after which the throttle will adaptively release). Your network throughput through the NAT will be choppy and sluggish in all but minimum load scenarios.

Comment: Excellent !! .. This is exactly the kind of insight I was seeking.  Thanks a million @Eight-Bit Guru.

Comment: Curious as to why this answer was just 'unaccepted' in favour of the other, less complete, answer...?

Comment: I agree with you, Eight-Bit-Guru .. your response is more complete, and that was why I accepted it.  At the time I was accepting it, I did not realize that accepting it meant un-accepting the other earlier answer.  But yeah, this is a more complete answer.  Will accept it again now ..

Comment: I've faced similar situations - I usually accept whichever answer best addresses the original question, and apply upvotes to any other answer which is close but not quite as complete and/or relevant. Sometimes it's a tough call on which to accept, and if so I usually explain my choice as a comment. It's always your call, however - I was merely curious since it had been accepted for a while and then suddenly wasn't, and I wondered why. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Network and CPU performance are also defined by instance type, and final performance is subject to many factors, so you would need to test and measure in your context to be sure.

That being said, i just ran iperf on my untuned, out-of-the-box m1.micro and got around 80 Mbits/sec. But that's just me...

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight, @Julio .. You are talking about the characteristics of an instance when used as an instance.  I am particularly interested in when an instance is used as a specialized NAT instance for use/deployment in a VPC.  I am curious to know if there are other considerations or limitations that the specialized usage may throw up.

Comment: When you create a "network element" in an instance (NAT, VPN Tunnel, web app firewall, etc), it is very important to monitor out network utilization (throughput is dependent on instance type) and configure for high availability (NAT becomes very often a single point of failure). All in all, monitor CPU/Net/Mem in CloudWatch and scale up as you go...

Comment: The NAT instance can be load-balanced with a trigger of 'zero -> one' so that if it dies or becomes unresponsive it will be terminated and a new one created. Any potential outage as a result of the loss of the NAT will thereby be reduced to a minimum.

Comment: Interesting approach @Eight-BitGuru, but then the wouldn't this load balancer instance become the new single point of failure?

Comment: Well, yes, but only in the same way that the host node your instances are running on could be considered a SPoF - if it dies, all the instances on it die. The load balancer service is probably load-balanced itself, since it's a service that a lot of people depend on. Arguably, if your load-balancer config fails to restart a dead NAT, you've probably got bigger problems than a loss of network connectivity to the estate (think AZ outage).

Answer (score 0):

The new generation t2 instances are more powerful and more cost-efficient than t1s. Using t2.micro, backed by SSD as Root device, is preferred over t1 in terms of spinning up NAT instances. Then use a pair of Auto scaling groups in a min of 2 AZs to build a HA, self-healing NATs.
Ensure use HVM-based (Virtualization Type) AMIs for t2 to support them.

Comment: I appreciate your response and was wondering about the t2's for NAT instances, but it doesn't really address @Eight-BitGuru's response, which is that the micro instances have highly variable network bandwidth, too.  Do you have an opinion on this?

Comment: I responded to OPs original concern, not to the response of the response
"Please, can anyone who has deployed this microinstance ami-vpc-nat (especially in production) share their thoughts on its performance and throughput."